# How to update the commit a git submodule points to if it does not point at the latest commit?

Tags: git, github

I have forked a repo which has some submodules. In one of these submodules I want to make an update to the code and then update the superproject such that it points to the commit I made to fix the submodule. What I have done so far:

- forked the superproject
- forked the submodule
- changed the `.gitmodules` file in the superproject to point to my fork
- `git submodule update --init` in my local clone of the superproject
- `cd submodule` and `git checkout` the commit the submodule is currently fixed to
- updated the submodule with my changes and created a new branch (because I otherwise I cannot push it since the HEAD is detached)
- `commit` and `push`ed the changes to the submodule into the new branch on remote
- cd `superproject` and commit and push the changes here as well

Yet when I `git clone superproject` and do `git submodule update --init` in it, I still get 'old' commit without my changes. However, I require this to get the submodule version with my changes, because it is part of a script. Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: I think this should work. Does the .gitmodules mention a branch? If that is different to the one you want, that could be the problem. Either change that, or remove the branch property there.

Comment: Your last bullet point, *cd superproject and commit and push the changes here as well*, does not mention `git add`: are you doing the `git add` of the submodule to record the new hash ID before doing the `git commit` step?

Comment: @torek I did `add` before. I manged to find the issue (see my answer below).

Comment: Ah, it was a cmake-related issue :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attempt listed above actually worked. The `CMakeLists.txt` in the subproject always checked out a hardcoded commit of the submodule, which cause the issue.